# Matrix of a linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a two-dimensional real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Consider the linear map $z \to e^{i\theta}z$ on $\mathbb{C}$.  What is the matrix of this map on $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual basis?

So the usual basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be $e^{i\theta}ze_1+e^{i\theta}ze_2$?  Which I would get to be $\left(\begin{array}{rr}e^{i\theta}z & 0 \\0 & e^{i\theta}z\end{array}\right)$.  Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite. Firstly $z$ shouldn't feature in your matrix. But notice that your matrix takes complex values

Comment: Presumably you are considering $\mathbb C/\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb R$, so the matrix can't have non-real entries.

Comment: Think about the real and imaginary components of $e^{i\theta}z$.

Comment: The real and imaginary components of $e^{i\theta}z$?  Isn't that $zcos(\theta )$ and $zsin(\theta )$?

Comment: What does the mapping $z \mapsto e^{i\theta}z$ do to $z$ geometrically?  If you figure that out you'll probably realize that you're already familiar with this matrix.

Comment: Does it map into polar coordinates?  So the matrix would just be $\begin{pmatrix} cos(\theta ) & sin(\theta ) \\ -sin(\theta ) & cos(\theta ) \end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 1):

For any linear transformation $T$, the matrix of a transformation from a space with basis $B = \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ is the matrix whose columns are the $T(e_1),\dots,T(e_n)$.

In this case, we are considering the space $\Bbb C$ (as a real vector space), which has basis $B = \{e_1=1,e_2=i\}$. We define this map by
$$
T \pmatrix{x\\y}_B = T (xe_1 + ye_2) = T(x+iy) = e^{i\theta} (x+iy)
$$
In order to find the columns of this matrix, we calculate:
$$
T \pmatrix{1\\0}_B = T(e_1) = e^{i \theta} \cdot1 = e^{i\theta} = 
\cos \theta + i \sin \theta = 
\cos \theta\, e_1 + \sin \theta\, e_2=
\pmatrix{\cos \theta\\ \sin \theta}_{B}
$$
Similarly,
$$
T \pmatrix{0\\1}_B = 
T(e_2) =
e^{i \theta} \cdot i = e^{i\theta} = 
i\cos \theta + i^2 \sin \theta = 
-\sin \theta\, e_1 + \cos \theta\, e_2=
\pmatrix{-\sin \theta\\ \cos \theta}_{B}
$$
So, the matrix of this transformation is
$$
\pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta}
$$